# Page View Controller Button Over All Views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

How can I add two buttons over all views in a page view controller. If I were to add them to each view separately, each swipe causes the buttons to be reloaded.

Is it possible to have buttons static over all views in a PageViewController, or would I need a container view with a page view controller inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like any scroll view: pin the buttons to the frame of something outside the page view controller's scroll view. The page view controller's own view would do, or the window, or whatever.

[image]